# Angular directive is not called from service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service which inject (*I know that's not good practice*) some markup in DOM, something like this:

```
app.service('CustomChartOptions', function() {
    this.getOptions = function() {
        var chartOptions = {
            return '<span some-directive>' + this.name + '</span>';
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code for my custom directive:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // it never gets fired
        }
    }
 });
```

So, the problem is that `someDirective` is not being called at runtime.

Comment: Should be `<span some-directive>`, no?

Comment: True, it was a typo. But the problem still exists. :(

Comment: I think you need to make an HTML element and compile it. `var elem = '<span some-directive>' + this.name + '</span>';` and then `$compile(elem)($rootScope.$new())`

Comment: Your code is invalid, returning from an object literal.

Comment: Why don't you invert control here and inject the service into the directive?

Comment: And that's why it's bad practice, because `$rootScope` might not contain what is actually needed by directive.

Comment: @goliney how else would you create a brand new scope for the directive, _from a service_?

Comment: @mparnisari short answer: I wouldn't. However, my upvotes of your comments say, that in the conditions that author creates - it's only possible solution.

Comment: @goliney ah, okay :)

Comment: Thanks all! Actually, I have inherit some code and I'm trying to figure out why it's not working... My starting point was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055188/displaying-bootstrap-popover-in-highchart-label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are just creating a string instead of an actual DOM element. You need to compile the element with the directive so that the `link` function is invoked.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, CustomChartOptions) {
  $scope.element = CustomChartOptions.getElement();
});

app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      alert('link function!');
    }
  }
});

app.service('CustomChartOptions', function($compile, $rootScope) {
  this.name = 'tom';
  this.getElement = function() {
      var compiledTemplate = $compile('<span some-directive>' + this.name + '</span>')($rootScope.$new());
      var elem = angular.element(compiledTemplate);
      return elem;
  };
  return this;
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HONtXWwrQQQj8EsAaz9N).

Comment: What should `getOptions` to return? `$scope.options` is undefined now

Comment: Ah it's true. I don't know, probably the element so that the controller can do something with it.